Remover duplicidade em elemento de uma lista em R
Preciso de um código que consiga remover a duplicidade nos elementos da lista, no caso remover um "aaa", a ideia é remover estes dados nas observações de um dataframe.
bb <- list("aaa, bbb, aaa, zzz", 
                     "qq, wz wa", 
                     "yyy, ww")


lapply(bb, \(b) paste(unique(strsplit(b, " ")[[1]]), collapse = " ")).

Tente dar mais contexto de sua dúvida na próxima! Assumindo que bb é a coluna de um dataframe, ele provavelmente vai ser um vetor (atômico), e não uma lista:
bb <- unlist(bb)

O algoritmo: para cada elemento de bb, separar seus "items", remover duplicatas, e juntar o resultado de volta.
Assumindo que o que separa cada "item" nos elementos de bb sempre é a string ", ":
bb_split <- strsplit(bb, ", ")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "aaa" "bbb" "aaa" "zzz"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "qq"    "wz wa"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "yyy" "ww" 

A seguir, precisamos fazer um loop para cada elemento de bb_split. Note que:

Nós iremos selecionar os elementos únicos com unique(bb_split[[i]]).
E unir o resultado novamente com paste0(..., collapse = ", ").
Lembrando que é mais eficiente criar o "contêiner" que receberá o resultado de antemão character(length(bb)).

bb_unique <- character(length(bb)) #contêiner

for (i in seq_along(bb_split)) {
  bb_unique[[i]] <- paste0(unique(bb_split[[i]]), collapse = ", ")
}

bb_unique
#> "aaa, bbb, zzz" "qq, wz wa" "yyy, ww"

Outra opção é, no lugar do loop, usar um "map" (uma ferramenta que aplica uma função à todos os elementos de um vetor):
vapply(
  strsplit(bb, ", "),
  \(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = ", "),
  character(1)
)

Há outros maps como o sapply(), mas eu gosto de vapply() porquê ele permite que a gente especifique o tipo do resultado, similar à como fizemos no contêiner.
